# How to set 'body' background in JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, dom

I try to change the 'body' element background when a button is clicked, however nothing happens and no error is returned in Chrome browser console. I have tried multiple methods. For **method 1**, I have also tried replacing **background** with **background-image**. In the CSS code, a background image is already assigned.

JS code:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    //method1:
    $('body').css({backgroundImage: 'url:(https://working-url)'});
    //method2:
    $('body').css('background', 'url:(https://working-url)');
}
```

CSS code refering to 'body':

```
html,
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

body {
 color: #F0F8FF ;
 background: url("back.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
 background-size: cover;
 font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

}
```

Comment: can you post fiddle?

Comment: `$('body').css({'backgroundImage': 'url(http://path-to-image)'});` -- You have a dangling colon `:` after url, remove that.

Comment: Try to inspect the code and see if the background property has changed. It may be that the body is covered by other elements and you don't see it. Also, put an alert("Hii") inside your `click function` to make sure it is working.

Comment: @Abhitalks Yes, that was the problem. Silly me :). You can answer the question if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to be careful when assigning the background is CSS with shorthand, which means assigning all the background properties in one line.  If you assign another background later, it will override ALL of those properties.  Meaning, since you are just adding the image, the `no-repeat center center fixed` will not transfer to the new background.  You need to set those properties separately and change only `background-image`.

As for the jQuery you want to target like this:

```
$('body').css('background-image', 'url(https://working-url)');
```

or

```
$('body').css({'background-image': 'url(https://working-url)'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML Button part:

```
<button>Change background</button>
```

JQUERY Part:

```
$('button').click(function(){
   $('body').css('background-image','image.jpg');
});
```